# Regex matching non-ASCII characters in sed

Tags: regex, sed

Consider the following sed regex replacement:

```
$ echo 'oóO' | sed -e 's/[^a-z]/./g'
oó.
```

To me, this says "replace all the characters not in the range from `a` to `z` with `.`, so I would expect the output `o..` since neither ó or O are in the range of `a-z` in the "codepoint" sense in any encoding (FWIW, I'm using UTF-8).

What's up with this?

How can i make a range that only matches exactly `[abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]` without writing it all out?

Here's the output of `locale` on my system:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: See if this helps https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multibyte-regexp-character-classes

Comment: @Quasímodo - that results in `o...`, so it seems like ó was treated as two separate characters and each was replaced (as expected, as C is a single-byte locale). Still, you gave me a hint ...

Comment: I get your expected result with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. What is your locale set to?

Comment: @MarkReed - I added the output of `locale` on my system to the question. My `sed` is `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`.

Comment: Huh. I was on MacOS. I do see your behavior on Ubuntu, but setting LC_COLLATE doesn't help there either. Curious.

Comment: @MarkReed, in my case `LC_COLLATE=C` does work, ubuntu 19.10. I think you have to unset `LC_ALL` for the `LC_COLLATE` to take effect: is that set on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Based on a variation of a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61329184/regex-matching-non-ascii-characters-in-sed/61329792#61329184) by Quasímodo, setting `LC_COLLATE=C` for the `sed` command works:

```sh
$ echo 'oóO' | LC_COLLATE=C sed -e 's/[^a-z]/./g'
o..
```

The key is to change the collation order to "C" so that ó does not appear anymore between o and p in the sort (collation) order, but *not* to change the `LC_CTYPE` (or `LC_ALL`), so that the multibyte UTF-8 characters are still interpreted correctly (this is why `LC_ALL=C` doesn't work).

Comment: Or just `echo oóO | LC_COLLATE=C sed -e 's/[^a-z]/./g'` if you don't want to leave LC_COLLATE set in your current shell environment.

Comment: @MarkReed, indeed, locally I actually did `(export LC_COLLATE=C; echo 'oóO' | sed -e 's/[^a-z]/./g')` to do everything in a subshell since I felt it's a bit weird to set the LC things differently for different parts of a pipeline, although for `LC_COLLATE` alone it is probably fine).